# Unable to establish a connection to adb

Tags: android-studio, adb, android-studio-3.0

I have problem in android studio when I want to run project that I made on my smartphone or even on Genymotion, anyone know how to fix it?
here the message:

Unable to establish a connection to adb.
this can happen if you have an incompatible version of adb running already.
try re-opening studio after killing any existing adb daemons.

Answer (score 0):

Connect phone to pc in adb mode, open command prompt in folder that contains the necessary adb files. At command prompt type "adb devices" without quotes and press enter. It should kill current daemon and restart adb. Will also show device connected